# Tomcat 9 slower skipping all jars tld scanning with defaultTldScan to false

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a Spring application deployed on a Tomcat 9 instance inside Spring Tools Suite 4.9.0 (based on Eclipse). After reading yet another time the message `At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs`, I decided to apply some configuration to get rid of it.

After reading [the Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/jar-scan-filter.html), I added the following `context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <JarScanner>
        <JarScanFilter defaultTldScan="false"/>
    </JarScanner>
</Context>
```

at `src/main/webapp/META-INF` (it's a Maven-managed application).

I started three times the server without that file (so with the original configuration) and three other times with that file in place, and I consistently got the following timings in the logs.

Without the `context.xml` file:

```
mar 11, 2021 2:27:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Server initialization in [1,861] milliseconds
mar 11, 2021 2:27:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting service [Catalina]
mar 11, 2021 ***2:27:52*** PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
mar 11, 2021 2:28:34 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
mar 11, 2021 ***2:28:43*** PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
...
```

with the file:

```
mar 11, 2021 3:12:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Server initialization in [1,520] milliseconds
mar 11, 2021 3:12:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting service [Catalina]
mar 11, 2021 ***3:12:44*** PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
mar 11, 2021 ***3:13:44*** PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
...
```

by the `*`-marked timings you can see that with jar scanning enabled I get a 50 seconds difference, whereas after disabling jar scanning that time difference jumps to around 60 secnds.

Tried this with Tomcat 9.0.30 and 9.0.43: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the log-level to debug to find the list of jars the cause this issue and then add them separately to your catalina configuration file. findout which jar first by setting log-level to debug and disable each of the jars(not *--mention each jar name in seperate lines) in catalina.properties and run the application again. Then report the time for Engine startup.

catalina.properties

tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=*.jar

Comment: Am I not completely disabling jar scanning with the above configuration? Afterwards no jar needs to be scanned, as I'm not using TLD's or JSP's